# error while fetching image from photo library and save to coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

**Error is below:**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'Contacts' in this model.'

**Code of fetching data from photo library**:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{    
     [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
      UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
      NSError *error;
      NSManagedObjectContext *context;
      context = [self managedObjectContext];

     NSManagedObject *object =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];

     NSData *data=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img,0.0);
     [object setValue:data forKey:@"image"];
     [context save:nil];
     [self fetchData];

 }
```

**My fetch() method coding.**

```
-(void)fetchData{

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contacts"
                               inManagedObjectContext:context]];
NSError * error = nil;
NSArray * objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if ([objects count] > 0) {
    NSManagedObject *object = objects[0];        
    data1 = [object valueForKey:@"image"];
    image2 = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data1];
    imgviewofprofilepic.image=image2;

}}
```

**And coding of NSManagedObjectContext()**

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
NSManagedObjectContext *context;
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
    context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
  return context;
 }
```

Comment: did you change the CoreData model between? First try to reset the simulator and run again. Also check your entity class name with entity name, they should match.

Comment: it's still not working. Retro

Comment: Can you provide the screen shot of your core data model file with all entities in it.

Comment: how to attach a image of screen shot in comment.

Comment: The context isn't nil? Your `managedObjectContext` getter could be returning nil.